# Counting NULL and spaces together in a file in UNIX

Tags: unix, awk, null, whitespace

I've to count the number of NULL values in a required field in a file in UNIX and I was using the folowing command

```
awk -F"|" '$3{NN++;next}
             {N++}
     END { print "Null: " N "   Not Null: " NN }' NULL_test.dat
```

Following is the sample file

```
cat NULL_test.dat
a|b|c|d
 |d|00|a
 || |x
s| ||a
0||0|0
1|2|3|4
```

Problem with above code is it consider [0] as NULL while spaces are considered as having values

```
Expected output was NULL : 2 NOT NULL: 4
Actual output is NULL : 3 NOT NULL: 3
```

Comment: did you want to count for null and not null  only on column 3? What do you mean by null and not null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't consider `0` as null, it considers `0` as zero. When you write a condition and action like `$3{do_foo}` you are specifically telling awk that you want to execute `do_foo` when `$3` is neither zero nor null nor all-blanks.

Use `$3==""` to specifically test only for null and use `$3~/^[[:blank:]]*$/` to test for null or all-blanks. This may be what you want:

```
$3~/^[[:blank:]]*$/{N++;next} {NN++}
```

Repeat/loop for other fields.